# issue in celery, the response took long time and still Sending request

Tags: django-rest-framework, redis, celery, signals

update:
using @app.task instead of @shared_task is solving the problem

---

I am making django signal that make a celery task when new compnay is create.

```py
# signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Company)
def company_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print(f'Signal connected for Company {instance.name}')
    if created:
        print(f'Company {instance.name} created') 
        process_new_company.delay(instance.name, instance.id)
```

```py
# tasks.py
@shared_task(bind=True) 
def process_new_company(self, company_name, company_id):
    logging.debug(f"Processing new company: {company_name} with id: {company_id}")
```

```py
# celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import task_failure

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'griphr-backend.settings')

app = Celery('griphr-backend')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')

# Using Redis as the result backend.
app.conf.broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.conf.result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

when i make POST: /company, i got this in server log:

`Signal connected for Company signals52-company`

`Company signals52-company created`
and the response isn't returned just (Sending request...) in postman

here is the output of the command `celery -A griphr-backend worker --loglevel=info`

> [tasks]
> company.tasks.process_new_company
> griphr-backend.celery.debug_task
>
> [2024-01-24 11:07:39,987: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
> [2024-01-24 11:07:39,995: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
> [2024-01-24 11:07:41,020: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
> [2024-01-24 11:07:41,033: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:202: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
> leak, never use this setting in production environments!
> warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
> [2024-01-24 11:07:41,034: INFO/MainProcess] celery@asus-k55a ready.

why the response isnt displayed and still sending request?

Comment: did you specify your celery_app in __init__.py file where settings.py file reside